# Resize a div element to its background image size

Tags: html, css, background

Is it possible to make a `<div>` adapt to its background image? I mean to maintain the proportions width and height.

Clarification:

- The `div` change the width. (it is a responsive design)
- I do not mean to make the background adapt to the div. This is possible with `background-size`. But what I am asking is the way round: **to have a image in the background and make the div parent adapt to that image whatever its size is**.
- I know that I can do something similar if I put the image in the html, and not in the background. But in this case, I could not change the image for different device sizes. So I am asking to put the image in background to be able to change it with CSS.

In the example I give, I can make the image adapt to the width but I get a gap with the height. Can I make the div adapt to the height too of the image , as the image changes its size? Asked in another way: In a responsive environment, can a div with an image background, change in size without leaving empty spaces ?

Here is [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/bH5JZ/1/) to play.

CSS:

```css
#image {
    margin:0px auto; 
    width:90%;
    max-width:512px;
    height:512px; /* I need to give heigt to make it visible? */

    background-image:url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-color:yellow;/*just to make visible the gap in the height*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, you HAVE to use height to make it visible, because otherwise, there will be no content to display, so the div will collapse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is NOT possible to adapt a div to it's background image.

Because it is 'senseless'

This is how:

A div's size is determined by its "content", or if its dimensions are SPECIFICALLY set.
Since the background-image does not fall into any of these categories, you can see that it's impossible.

What you CAN do is this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="image-controlled">
  <img>...</img>
  <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
 .image-controlled {
   position: relative; 
   overflow: hidden <-- optional, if you want to cut off .content which overflows the image boundaries
 }
 .content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; <-- position of the content as it should be (normally)
 }
```

The div will now be the size of the image, and the `.content` will be shown over it.

---

Also note that the `.content` div can come above or below the `<img>` in order of appearance, but the effect would be the same. But, if you apply a `position` property on the `img` element too, then you'll need to set the `z-index` of `.content` greater than that of `<img>`

Answer (score 3):

By using CSS, It's not possible to change an element's dimension according to its `background-image` size, to achieve this, you should use JavaScript:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var 
    img = document.getElementById('image'),
    style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
    imgSrc = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1),
    image = new Image();

image.src = imgSrc;
img.style.width = image.width + 'px';
img.style.height = image.height + 'px';
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/fxrH2/1/)**

---

#### Update: *jQuery version*

Here is the the jQuery version.

```
var
    img = $('#image'),
    imgSrc = img.css('background-image').slice(4, -1);

$('<img />')
    .attr('src', imgSrc)
    .on('load', function() {
        img.width(this.width);
        img.height(this.height);
    });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/fxrH2/2/)**

Comment: Sorry I am not good enough with pure Javascript. I am more used to jQuery. So I am not able to appreciate your code nor apply it to my case

Comment: @Nrc I've added the jQuery version and demo.

Comment: In the above example, we create an `img` element on the fly, set the `src` attribute and after loading the image, get its dimension and change `width` and `height` of our division `#image`.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. We can make background image adapt to its div, like make it responsive too.

Tips for a responsive background image:
`background-size:cover`
-set bg image to background-size cover

-in css the padding set to percentage both top and bottom

-make the bg image no repeat

see this link: https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/dtxLjmdv/

Comment: Interesting solution. How do you calculate the padding top and bottom?

Comment: background-attachment:cover I think does not exist. I think you mean background-size:cover;

Comment: you have to adjust a little until same with the image size, make top and bottom same and make sure the unit is in percent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using javascript, you can get the url to the image:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage; 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
document.getElemetById('image').style.width = width;
document.getElemetById('image').style.height = height;
```

I strongly suspect you cannot do this exclusively with stylesheets.

Comment: Could you do this with jQuery? I think I will understand better

Comment: I am not good at jQuery, however it must be something really similar. Instead of getElementById you gonna write $('image'), then use js to get the dimensions of the image than set the appropriate style parametrs to the variables you just got.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my solution is a little bit tricky, but it works. It's a javascript and involve jquery as you wanted. The idea is to create a new image, add it to the DOM, waits till it loads and gets its dimensions. After that the new image is removed and the width and height are applied to the original *img* tag. Here is a js fiddle demonstrating the workaround http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/bH5JZ/5/

And here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = $("#image");
    var imageurl = image.css("background-image").replace(/url/, '').replace(/\(/, '').replace(/\)/, '');
    var body = $("body");

    var newimage = $('<img src="' + imageurl + '" />');
    newimage.css("display", "none");
    body.append(newimage);
    newimage.on("load", function() {
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).height();
        image.css("width", w);
        image.css("height", h);
        newimage.remove();
    });
});
```

And the css:

```
#image {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image:url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do that doesn't need any javascript is to set your image as the background image and then make a .gif or a .png of the same size that you set as an overlay image in that div. That transparent .png or .gif will size the div. Transparent .png or .gif are only a couple of KB and your page will complete loading faster than with javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div {
        background-image:url("myImage.jpg");
        background-size:100% auto;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><img alt="" src="myOverlay.png"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```