# Responsively resize div according to its background image height

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, background-image

So, here the background-size of `<main>` element is `contain`, which cause it's container `#main` contains the space towards the bottom on lower screen sizes.

So, I wanted to resize the height of `#main` responsively according to `<main>`'s background-image height to remove the vertical gap in lower screen sizes.

Note that the background image **shouldn't** be stretched or hidden.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <main>

    </main>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
main{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(images/img-main.png) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```javascript
var toHeight = $('main')//?????? I'm stacked here 
$('#main').css('height',toHeight);
```

Any ideas?

---

Here's the **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/)** (resize the window to understand)

```
+--------------------------+--------
|                          |
|    background-image      |
|              height      |       main
|                          |
|                          |      height
+--------------------------+
|         vertical         |
|           gap            |
+--------------------------+---------
```

Should be converted to:

```
+--------------------------+--------
|                          |       main
|    background-image      |
|              height      |     height
|                          |
|                          | 
+--------------------------+----------
```

Comment: making `height:auto` must do the job.

Comment: height: auto; doesn't work because its in percent.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery?lq=1

Comment: main's background-image height has allways the same size as main's height and if there is no padding and no margin, #main's height is equal too... I think your question or your problem isn't clear...

Comment: JSFiddle with your situation to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/y7dmG/

Comment: @C-link Did you check my posted link? This question has already an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18297940/1725764

Comment: @HashemQolami please try to answer me taking my jsfiddle. I couldn't understand that.

Comment: As @HashemQolami mentioned, why not just use a normal `<img>` tag instead of `background-image` in css? That way the parent div can scale according to the image size.

Comment: That way too, not fine what I wanted. The image shouldn't be stretched or hidden.

Comment: @C-link The image won't be stretched or hidden even if you use the `<img>` tag, unless you specifically put it in your css to stretch / hide it.

Comment: @C-link Your update is still not clear. Please choose what you want to do: 1) I want the main div height to scale with the image height. 2) I want the image height to scale with the main div height. 3) I want to set the heights myself.

Comment: @DarkAshelin option 2

Comment: @C-link Then either http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/6/ or http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/7/ should be the working option for you.

Comment: you didn't have set height in main div. but I wanted to get the image height as per the main div height.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49541/discussion-between-dark-ashelin-and-c-link)

Comment: @C-link I've updated my given answer to fit your needs. Please give it a try and let me know how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated Answer

### Testing the old answer

During testing I found out that the old approach (creating an image element on the fly to get its dimensions) [**only works on latest versions**](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/75e462b9a09a3306a88315ef1d72413ed6e0a39f) of Chrome, Safari and Firefox but not IE. Thus it's not a cross browser method.

### What the OP really wants

In addition, as per the OP's comments below, I figured it out that the OP wants the `<main>` element to be `70%` of height of the browser. But **Once** the *width* of the `<main>` element reaches the *edges* of the background image by resizing the window horizontally, the *height* `<main>` element should be **reduced** to remove the vertical gap between the background image.

*(That vertical gap happens because of using `contain` value for the background image to keep the image inside of the box and keeping the aspect ratio)*.

Considering that, and our failure to get the dimensions of the background image on-the-fly with a large scale of web browsers, you'll end up with the following:

```javascript
var main = $('#main'),
    imgwidth  = 500,  // Set the width/height of the background image manually
    imgHeight = 300,
    imgRatio  = imgHeight/imgwidth,
    mainHeight   = main.height();

$(window).resize(function() {
  var mainWidth  = main.width(),
      mainRatio  = mainHeight/mainWidth;

  // Compare ratio of the <main> element and the background image
  if (mainRatio >= imgRatio) {
    main.height(imgRatio * mainWidth);
  } else {
    main.height('70%');
  }
}).resize(); // Trigger the handler once the script is loaded
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qacix/1/edit)**.

---

## The old Answer *<sup>(Under a misconception)</sup>*

There's no pure CSS way to resize an element's dimensions according to its background-image.

You'll need to use JavaScript to achieve that. By using JavaScript we get the computed `background-image` and create an image element (using the background image) on the fly to get the dimensions of the background image

Here you go:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <main id="main"></main>
    <div>another div</div>
</div>
```

<sub>I've combined two `#main` and `<main>` elements to condense the markup in this particulat instance.</sub>

jQuery version:

```javascript
var
    main = $('#main'),
    imgSrc = main.css('background-image').slice(4, -1);

$('<img />')
    .attr('src', imgSrc)
    .on('load', function() {
        main.height(this.height);
    });
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wAJyv/2/)**.

Comment: It's not working. See by resizing!

Comment: You are targeting to img tag but I think it should be main tag.

Comment: @C-link `I wanted to set the #main's height according to main's background-image height.` That was my assumption. *background-image height* is fixed in px units.

Comment: Yeah, then you are right but when you reisze to small then you'll see bottom space there.

Comment: There's something wrong. Please carefully see your code.

Comment: @C-link That's because of `background-size: contain;`. You could change that to `background-size: auto 100%;` to fit the height.

Comment: No, I must use contain to get picture's visibility without stretch and without hidden.

Comment: @C-link Sorry, but I don't understand what exactly you want. I'll be appreciated if you could update the question to add more details.

Comment: you should see the demo in my question by resizing the window to small then you'll see the gap there. and the image is not stretched. That's what I want but without the space. clear?

Comment: If you place auto 100% then the image part will be hidden. That I don't want.

Comment: @C-link Ok, I think I've got it. let me update the fiddle.

Comment: @C-link Please check this **[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wAJyv/5/)** Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: not, still space the yellow background..

Comment: @C-link Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/7/ (see my answer)

Comment: @DarkAshelin I'm trying your method but not working as height is set in percentage.

Comment: You either set your own height (in %) or let it be resized by the image. You can't have both.
You can choose a `min-height` if that's what you want.

Comment: @DarkAshelin I tried your method is working perfectly. thanks. I'll accept your answer if it's not possible with background image.

Comment: @DarkAshelin But sorry, it's not setting image height.

Comment: @C-link Can you be more detailed? I don't understand you.

Comment: @DarkAshelin see this http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/8/ main height is set to 70%; and thus image height should be accordingly.

Comment: @C-link I think you should make up your mind and think deeply what you really want and what is logically **possible**. You can't have the main div height scale according to img size, and at the same time have img scale according to main div height, and at the same time choose the height by yourself. Think logically. It sounds like you want both a circle and a square (metaphor)

Comment: Please check my update that would be clear?

Comment: @C-link I've updated the **[demo](http://jsbin.com/yuxav/1/edit)** please give it a try.

Comment: @HashemQolami It's now hiding the image as you are using auto 100%.

Comment: then the space i.e. yellow part in your demo is not removed that is the main's height is not set.

Comment: @C-link I withdrew my last comment, But still using `auto 100%` doesn't hide the background image as I'm handling the scale of the main element by javascript. Please replace your own image into the demo to verfy that.

Comment: nope. it's hiding you can see by resizing

Comment: Discussion has been moved to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49541/discussion-between-dark-ashelin-and-c-link

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was willing to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using an `<img>` tag instead of the `background-image` attribute:

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqHMio3jll2W62WXJHbufc-xxYPxec_ip8Ez0lQv2P7Umy2kPKrw">
    </div>
    <div>another div</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#main{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle; //prevents a default bottom margin from appearing
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/6/ (try resizing)

Edit: **Alternatively**, if you want the image to be scaled upwards too incase the main div is wider, you can simply use `width: 100%` instead of `max-width: 100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/wAJyv/7/

Answer (score 0):

give `background-size: 100% 100%;` in the css of `.main` than contain.

```
.main {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: that stretches the image.